# How to Eval Decode JavaScript Without redirecting to the copywright owner homepage

Tags: javascript, redirect, eval, decode

```
var _mSAeHR= "\x65\x76\x61\x6c\x28\x66\x75\x6e\x63\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x28\x70\x2c\x61\x2c\x63\x2c\x6b\x2c\x65\x2c\x64\x29\x7b\x65\x3d\x66\x75\x6e\x63\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x28\x63\x29\x7b\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6e\x28\x63\x3c\x61\x3f\x27\x27\x3a\x65\x28\x70\x61\x72\x73\x65\x49\x6e\x74\x28\x63\x2f\x61\x29\x29\x29\x2b\x28\x28\x63\x3d\x63\x25\x61\x29\x3e\x33\x35\x3f\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67\x2e\x66\x72\x6f\x6d\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6f\x64\x65\x28\x63\x2b\x32\x39\x29\x3a\x63\x2e\x74\x6f\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67\x28\x33\x36\x29\x29\x7d\x3b\x69\x66\x28\x21\x27\x27\x2e\x72\x65\x70\x6c\x61\x63\x65\x28\x2f\x5e\x2f\x2c\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67\x29\x29\x7b\x77\x68\x69\x6c\x65\x28\x63\x2d\x2d\x29\x7b\x64\x5b\x65\x28\x63\x29\x5d\x3d\x6b\x5b\x63\x5d\x7c\x7c\x65\x28\x63\x29\x7d\x6b\x3d\x5b\x66\x75\x6e\x63\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x28\x65\x29\x7b\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6e\x20\x64\x5b\x65\x5d\x7d\x5d\x3b\x65\x3d\x66\x75\x6e\x63\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x28\x29\x7b\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6e\x27\x5c\x5c\x77\x2b\x27\x7d\x3b\x63\x3d\x31\x7d\x3b\x77\x68\x69\x6c\x65\x28\x63\x2d\x2d\x29\x7b\x69\x66\x28\x6b\x5b\x63\x5d\x29\x7b\x70\x3d\x70\x2e\x72\x65\x70\x6c\x61\x63\x65\x28\x6e\x65\x77\x20\x52\x65\x67\x45\x78\x70\x28\x27\x5c\x5c\x62\x27\x2b\x65\x28\x63\x29\x2b\x27\x5c\x5c\x62\x27\x2c\x27\x67\x27\x29\x2c\x6b\x5b\x63\x5d\x29\x7d\x7d\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6e\x20\x70\x7d\x28\x27\x5c\x27\x6a\x63\x20\x62\x77\x5c\x27\x3b\x64\x20\x33\x31\x3d\x5a\x3b\x28\x6b\x28\x38\x6b\x2c\x61\x4b\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x31\x6a\x3d\x5a\x2c\x33\x4f\x3d\x38\x6b\x28\x29\x3b\x63\x30\x28\x21\x21\x5b\x5d\x29\x7b\x38\x50\x7b\x64\x20\x61\x76\x3d\x2d\x31\x74\x28\x31\x6a\x28\x62\x6d\x29\x29\x2f\x42\x2a\x28\x31\x74\x28\x31\x6a\x28\x62\x52\x29\x29\x2f\x33\x48\x29\x2b\x31\x74\x28\x31\x6a\x28\x61\x4c\x29\x29\x2f\x36\x79\x2a\x28\x31\x74\x28\x31\x6a\x28\x62\x35\x29\x29\x2f\x35\x61\x29\x2b\x2d\x31\x74\x28\x31\x6a\x28\x62\x61\x29\x29\x2f\x37\x4c\x2a\x28\x2d\x31\x74\x28\x31\x6a\x28\x61\x51\x29\x29\x2f\x64\x6d\x29\x2b\x2d\x31\x74\x28\x31\x6a\x28\x64\x58\x29\x29\x2f\x64\x56\x2b\x31\x74\x28\x31\x6a\x28\x64\x46\x29\x29\x2f\x64\x69\x2b\x31\x74\x28\x31\x6a\x28\x61\x5a\x29\x29\x2f\x61\x4f\x2a\x28\x31\x74\x28\x31\x6a\x28\x63\x36\x29\x29\x2f\x64\x4e\x29\x2b\x31\x74\x28\x31\x6a\x28\x62\x54\x29\x29\x2f\x62\x39\x3b\x69\x66\x28\x61\x76\x3d\x3d\x3d\x61\x4b\x29\x39\x37\x3b\x31\x42\x20\x33\x4f\x5b\x5c\x27\x34\x6c\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x33\x4f\x5b\x5c\x27\x61\x6b\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x29\x29\x7d\x39\x32\x28\x64\x62\x29\x7b\x33\x4f\x5b\x5c\x27\x34\x6c\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x33\x4f\x5b\x5c\x27\x61\x6b\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x29\x29\x7d\x7d\x7d\x28\x32\x58\x2c\x64\x44\x29\x29\x3b\x6b\x20\x5a\x28\x61\x45\x2c\x39\x67\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x61\x71\x3d\x32\x58\x28\x29\x3b\x53\x20\x5a\x3d\x6b\x28\x34\x50\x2c\x64\x45\x29\x7b\x34\x50\x3d\x34\x50\x2d\x61\x6a\x3b\x64\x20\x61\x44\x3d\x61\x71\x5b\x34\x50\x5d\x3b\x53\x20\x61\x44\x7d\x2c\x5a\x28\x61\x45\x2c\x39\x67\x29\x7d\x64\x20\x24\x36\x74\x3d\x33\x31\x28\x64\x33\x29\x3b\x6b\x20\x61\x33\x28\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x4d\x3d\x33\x31\x3b\x6b\x20\x64\x34\x28\x31\x6f\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x31\x54\x3d\x5a\x2c\x39\x51\x3b\x53\x21\x6b\x20\x63\x76\x28\x36\x48\x29\x7b\x38\x50\x7b\x53\x20\x64\x39\x28\x39\x59\x28\x36\x48\x29\x29\x3d\x3d\x36\x48\x7d\x39\x32\x28\x64\x74\x29\x7b\x53\x21\x42\x7d\x7d\x28\x31\x6f\x29\x3f\x5c\x27\x5c\x27\x3a\x31\x6f\x3d\x28\x39\x51\x3d\x31\x6f\x3d\x28\x31\x6f\x3d\x28\x31\x6f\x3d\x28\x31\x6f\x3d\x28\x31\x6f\x3d\x28\x31\x6f\x3d\x28\x31\x6f\x3d\x28\x31\x6f\x3d\x39\x59\x28\x31\x6f\x29\x29\x5b\x31\x54\x28\x33\x63\x29\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x62\x55\x5c\x27\x2c\x5c\x27\x2e\x5c\x27\x29\x29\x5b\x5c\x27\x35\x6d\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x62\x59\x5c\x27\x2c\x5c\x27\x2d\x5c\x27\x29\x29\x5b\x5c\x27\x35\x6d\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x62\x42\x5c\x27\x2c\x5c\x27\x61\x5c\x27\x29\x29\x5b\x31\x54\x28\x33\x63\x29\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x62\x4d\x5c\x27\x2c\x5c\x27\x69\x5c\x27\x29\x29\x5b\x31\x54\x28\x33\x63\x29\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x62\x41\x5c\x27\x2c\x5c\x27\x75\x5c\x27\x29\x29\x5b\x31\x54\x28\x33\x63\x29\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x65\x33\x5c\x27\x2c\x5c\x27\x65\x5c\x27\x29\x29\x5b\x31\x54\x28\x33\x63\x29\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x62\x4c\x5c\x27\x2c\x5c\x27\x6f\x5c\x27\x29\x29\x5b\x31\x54\x28\x31\x65\x29\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x5c\x27\x29\x5b\x31\x54\x28\x62\x44\x29\x5d\x28\x29\x5b\x31\x54\x28\x34\x52\x29\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x5c\x27\x29\x7d\x69\x66\x28\x2d\x42\x3d\x3d\x33\x6e\x5b\x4d\x28\x39\x43\x29\x5d\x5b\x5c\x27\x39\x55\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x4d\x28\x62\x7a\x29\x29\x7c\x7c\x2d\x42\x3d\x3d\x33\x6e\x5b\x4d\x28\x39\x43\x29\x5d\x5b\x4d\x28\x32\x6a\x29\x5d\x28\x4d\x28\x63\x62\x29\x29\x7c\x7c\x2d\x42\x3d\x3d\x33\x6e\x5b\x5c\x27\x61\x6c\x5c\x27\x5d\x5b\x4d\x28\x32\x6a\x29\x5d\x28\x4d\x28\x63\x61\x29\x29\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x35\x31\x3d\x32\x6f\x5b\x4d\x28\x39\x50\x29\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x63\x38\x5c\x27\x29\x3b\x69\x66\x28\x61\x31\x3d\x3d\x3d\x35\x31\x29\x7b\x32\x6f\x5b\x5c\x27\x32\x66\x5c\x27\x5d\x5b\x4d\x28\x36\x4a\x29\x5d\x3d\x4d\x28\x63\x37\x29\x2b\x24\x36\x74\x2b\x4d\x28\x63\x35\x29\x3b\x64\x20\x35\x39\x3d\x63\x33\x3b\x63\x31\x28\x6b\x28\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x33\x65\x3d\x4d\x3b\x32\x6f\x5b\x33\x65\x28\x39\x50\x29\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x62\x56\x5c\x27\x29\x5b\x33\x65\x28\x36\x4a\x29\x5d\x3d\x35\x39\x2c\x46\x3d\x3d\x35\x39\x3f\x33\x6e\x5b\x33\x65\x28\x32\x37\x29\x5d\x3d\x33\x65\x28\x62\x53\x29\x3a\x35\x39\x2d\x2d\x7d\x2c\x37\x59\x29\x7d\x31\x42\x20\x35\x31\x5b\x4d\x28\x36\x4a\x29\x5d\x3d\x4d\x28\x61\x4d\x29\x2b\x24\x36\x74\x2b\x4d\x28\x62\x66\x29\x2c\x35\x31\x5b\x4d\x28\x62\x32\x29\x5d\x28\x4d\x28\x62\x38\x29\x2c\x4d\x28\x62\x6b\x29\x29\x7d\x7d\x6b\x20\x61\x35\x28\x29\x7b\x24\x28\x6b\x28\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x6c\x3d\x5a\x3b\x6b\x20\x39\x61\x28\x34\x62\x2c\x34\x65\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x32\x6b\x3d\x5a\x3b\x35\x4e\x28\x64\x20\x33\x44\x3d\x46\x3b\x33\x44\x3c\x34\x62\x5b\x34\x65\x5d\x5b\x32\x6b\x28\x36\x55\x29\x5d\x5b\x32\x6b\x28\x31\x59\x29\x5d\x3b\x33\x44\x2b\x2b\x29\x69\x66\x28\x32\x6b\x28\x61\x53\x29\x3d\x3d\x34\x62\x5b\x34\x65\x5d\x5b\x5c\x27\x32\x75\x5c\x27\x5d\x5b\x33\x44\x5d\x5b\x32\x6b\x28\x64\x61\x29\x5d\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x39\x73\x3d\x34\x62\x5b\x34\x65\x5d\x5b\x32\x6b\x28\x36\x55\x29\x5d\x5b\x33\x44\x5d\x5b\x32\x6b\x28\x32\x37\x29\x5d\x3b\x39\x37\x7d\x53\x20\x39\x73\x7d\x6b\x20\x39\x39\x28\x39\x30\x2c\x38\x59\x2c\x39\x31\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x36\x4b\x3d\x5a\x3b\x53\x5c\x27\x3c\x61\x5c\x5c\x31\x41\x3d\x5c\x5c\x6a\x5c\x27\x2b\x39\x31\x2b\x5c\x27\x5c\x5c\x6a\x3e\x5c\x27\x2b\x39\x30\x5b\x38\x59\x5d\x5b\x36\x4b\x28\x34\x67\x29\x5d\x5b\x5c\x27\x24\x74\x5c\x27\x5d\x2b\x36\x4b\x28\x34\x55\x29\x7d\x6b\x20\x61\x61\x28\x33\x74\x2c\x33\x68\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x4e\x3d\x5a\x2c\x38\x55\x3d\x33\x74\x5b\x33\x68\x5d\x5b\x5c\x27\x32\x77\x5c\x27\x5d\x5b\x5c\x27\x24\x74\x5c\x27\x5d\x2c\x34\x6b\x3d\x33\x74\x5b\x33\x68\x5d\x5b\x4e\x28\x61\x42\x29\x5d\x5b\x5c\x27\x24\x74\x5c\x27\x5d\x2c\x38\x4d\x3d\x24\x28\x4e\x28\x61\x49\x29\x29\x5b\x4e\x28\x54\x29\x5d\x28\x34\x6b\x29\x3b\x69\x66\x28\x4e\x28\x38\x56\x29\x69\x6e\x20\x33\x74\x5b\x33\x68\x5d\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x36\x45\x3d\x33\x74\x5b\x33\x68\x5d\x5b\x4e\x28\x38\x56\x29\x5d\x5b\x4e\x28\x31\x76\x29\x5d\x2c\x34\x6d\x3d\x36\x45\x5b\x4e\x28\x31\x6e\x29\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x2f\x39\x6c\x2d\x63\x5c\x27\x2c\x5c\x27\x2f\x64\x67\x5c\x27\x29\x3b\x34\x6b\x5b\x4e\x28\x32\x6a\x29\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x64\x66\x2e\x31\x43\x2f\x64\x64\x5c\x27\x29\x3e\x2d\x42\x26\x26\x28\x34\x6d\x3d\x36\x45\x5b\x4e\x28\x31\x6e\x29\x5d\x28\x4e\x28\x65\x32\x29\x2c\x4e\x28\x64\x59\x29\x29\x29\x7d\x31\x42\x20\x34\x6d\x3d\x34\x6b\x5b\x4e\x28\x32\x6a\x29\x5d\x28\x4e\x28\x64\x57\x29\x29\x3e\x2d\x42\x3f\x38\x4d\x5b\x4e\x28\x77\x29\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x32\x67\x3a\x31\x48\x5c\x27\x29\x5b\x4e\x28\x31\x55\x29\x5d\x28\x4e\x28\x38\x71\x29\x29\x3a\x36\x6b\x3b\x53\x20\x4e\x28\x64\x55\x29\x2b\x38\x55\x2b\x4e\x28\x61\x46\x29\x2b\x34\x6d\x2b\x5c\x27\x5c\x5c\x6a\x2f\x3e\x5c\x27\x7d\x6b\x20\x61\x63\x28\x38\x54\x2c\x38\x52\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x31\x58\x3d\x5a\x2c\x38\x51\x3d\x38\x54\x5b\x38\x52\x5d\x5b\x5c\x27\x32\x79\x5c\x27\x5d\x5b\x5c\x27\x24\x74\x5c\x27\x5d\x2c\x36\x71\x3d\x24\x28\x5c\x27\x3c\x78\x3e\x5c\x27\x29\x5b\x31\x58\x28\x54\x29\x5d\x28\x38\x51\x29\x2c\x36\x43\x3d\x36\x71\x5b\x31\x58\x28\x77\x29\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x33\x6f\x3a\x33\x70\x28\x5c\x5c\x37\x36\x2f\x5c\x5c\x6a\x29\x5c\x27\x29\x2c\x37\x35\x3d\x36\x71\x5b\x31\x58\x28\x77\x29\x5d\x28\x31\x58\x28\x35\x56\x29\x29\x3b\x69\x66\x28\x36\x43\x5b\x31\x58\x28\x31\x59\x29\x5d\x3e\x46\x29\x64\x20\x34\x31\x3d\x36\x43\x5b\x31\x58\x28\x31\x66\x29\x5d\x28\x29\x2c\x33\x5a\x3d\x34\x31\x5b\x31\x58\x28\x31\x65\x29\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x2f\x5c\x27\x29\x2c\x36\x58\x3d\x33\x5a\x5b\x42\x5d\x3b\x69\x66\x28\x37\x35\x5b\x5c\x27\x34\x71\x5c\x27\x5d\x3e\x46\x29\x64\x20\x34\x31\x3d\x37\x35\x5b\x5c\x27\x32\x32\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x29\x2c\x33\x5a\x3d\x34\x31\x5b\x5c\x27\x32\x64\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x2f\x5c\x27\x29\x2c\x36\x56\x3d\x33\x5a\x5b\x42\x5d\x3b\x69\x66\x28\x35\x66\x20\x46\x21\x3d\x36\x58\x29\x64\x20\x36\x6c\x3d\x5c\x27\x3c\x48\x5c\x5c\x79\x3d\x5c\x5c\x63\x44\x2d\x34\x48\x5c\x5c\x6a\x3e\x5c\x27\x2b\x36\x58\x2b\x5c\x27\x3c\x2f\x48\x3e\x5c\x27\x3b\x31\x42\x20\x36\x6c\x3d\x5c\x27\x5c\x27\x3b\x69\x66\x28\x35\x66\x20\x46\x21\x3d\x36\x56\x29\x64\x20\x35\x76\x3d\x5c\x27\x3c\x48\x5c\x5c\x79\x3d\x5c\x5c\x63\x43\x5c\x5c\x63\x42\x5c\x5c\x6a\x3e\x5c\x27\x2b\x36\x56\x2b\x31\x58\x28\x63\x77\x29\x3b\x31\x42\x20\x35\x76\x3d\x5c\x27\x5c\x27\x3b\x53\x5b\x36\x6c\x2c\x35\x76\x5d\x7d\x6b\x20\x33\x32\x28\x32\x4c\x2c\x56\x2c\x33\x6b\x2c\x32\x70\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x52\x3d\x5a\x3b\x69\x66\x28\x56\x5b\x5c\x27\x32\x41\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x34\x76\x2d\x31\x70\x5c\x27\x29\x7c\x7c\x56\x5b\x52\x28\x31\x35\x29\x5d\x28\x52\x28\x35\x4c\x29\x29\x7c\x7c\x56\x5b\x52\x28\x31\x35\x29\x5d\x28\x52\x28\x63\x68\x29\x29\x7c\x7c\x56\x5b\x5c\x27\x32\x41\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x52\x28\x39\x66\x29\x29\x7c\x7c\x56\x5b\x52\x28\x31\x35\x29\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x33\x69\x5c\x27\x29\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x35\x43\x3d\x5c\x27\x5c\x27\x3b\x35\x43\x3d\x52\x28\x63\x71\x29\x3d\x3d\x32\x70\x3f\x52\x28\x63\x70\x29\x2b\x33\x6b\x3a\x52\x28\x34\x30\x29\x3d\x3d\x32\x70\x3f\x52\x28\x63\x6f\x29\x2b\x33\x6b\x2b\x52\x28\x63\x6e\x29\x2b\x28\x33\x58\x5b\x52\x28\x38\x63\x29\x5d\x28\x33\x58\x5b\x52\x28\x34\x30\x29\x5d\x28\x29\x2a\x33\x6b\x29\x2b\x42\x29\x2b\x5c\x27\x26\x33\x64\x3d\x33\x73\x2d\x69\x6e\x2d\x35\x4d\x5c\x27\x3a\x5c\x27\x2f\x32\x50\x2f\x31\x71\x2f\x32\x62\x2f\x2d\x2f\x5c\x27\x2b\x32\x70\x2b\x5c\x27\x3f\x33\x64\x3d\x33\x73\x2d\x69\x6e\x2d\x35\x4d\x26\x31\x52\x2d\x32\x69\x3d\x5c\x27\x2b\x33\x6b\x2c\x24\x5b\x52\x28\x36\x34\x29\x5d\x28\x7b\x5c\x27\x32\x68\x5c\x27\x3a\x35\x43\x2c\x5c\x27\x36\x63\x5c\x27\x3a\x52\x28\x63\x75\x29\x2c\x5c\x27\x36\x65\x5c\x27\x3a\x5c\x27\x36\x69\x5c\x27\x2c\x5c\x27\x39\x44\x5c\x27\x3a\x6b\x28\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x33\x30\x3d\x52\x3b\x56\x5b\x33\x30\x28\x31\x35\x29\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x32\x51\x2d\x31\x71\x5c\x27\x29\x26\x26\x32\x4c\x5b\x33\x30\x28\x54\x29\x5d\x28\x33\x30\x28\x63\x48\x29\x29\x5b\x5c\x27\x34\x45\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x29\x5b\x5c\x27\x31\x46\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x33\x30\x28\x61\x79\x29\x29\x7d\x2c\x5c\x27\x36\x32\x5c\x27\x3a\x6b\x28\x39\x64\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x6e\x3d\x52\x3b\x69\x66\x28\x56\x5b\x5c\x27\x32\x41\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x34\x76\x2d\x31\x70\x5c\x27\x29\x29\x64\x20\x31\x44\x3d\x6e\x28\x64\x30\x29\x3b\x31\x42\x7b\x69\x66\x28\x56\x5b\x6e\x28\x31\x35\x29\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x32\x51\x2d\x31\x71\x5c\x27\x29\x29\x64\x20\x31\x44\x3d\x6e\x28\x63\x4a\x29\x3b\x31\x42\x7b\x69\x66\x28\x56\x5b\x6e\x28\x31\x35\x29\x5d\x28\x6e\x28\x39\x66\x29\x29\x29\x64\x20\x31\x44\x3d\x6e\x28\x63\x54\x29\x3b\x31\x42\x7b\x69\x66\x28\x56\x5b\x6e\x28\x31\x35\x29\x5d\x28\x6e\x28\x61\x70\x29\x29\x29\x64\x20\x31\x44\x3d\x5c\x27\x3c\x49\x5c\x5c\x79\x3d\x5c\x5c\x37\x67\x2d\x31\x71\x5c\x5c\x63\x53\x5c\x5c\x6a\x3e\x5c\x27\x7d\x7d\x7d\x64\x20\x35\x68\x3d\x39\x64\x5b\x6e\x28\x61\x62\x29\x5d\x5b\x6e\x28\x36\x78\x29\x5d\x3b\x69\x66\x28\x35\x66\x20\x46\x21\x3d\x35\x68\x29\x7b\x35\x4e\x28\x64\x20\x31\x72\x3d\x46\x2c\x32\x42\x3d\x35\x68\x3b\x31\x72\x3c\x32\x42\x5b\x6e\x28\x31\x59\x29\x5d\x3b\x31\x72\x2b\x2b\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x32\x4d\x3d\x39\x61\x28\x32\x42\x2c\x31\x72\x29\x2c\x33\x72\x3d\x39\x39\x28\x32\x42\x2c\x31\x72\x2c\x32\x4d\x29\x2c\x33\x71\x3d\x61\x61\x28\x32\x42\x2c\x31\x72\x29\x2c\x31\x56\x3d\x61\x63\x28\x32\x42\x2c\x31\x72\x29\x2c\x32\x49\x3d\x5c\x27\x5c\x27\x3b\x56\x5b\x6e\x28\x31\x35\x29\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x34\x76\x2d\x31\x70\x5c\x27\x29\x3f\x32\x49\x2b\x3d\x5c\x27\x3c\x78\x5c\x5c\x79\x3d\x5c\x5c\x37\x32\x2d\x32\x30\x5c\x5c\x34\x36\x2d\x5c\x27\x2b\x31\x72\x2b\x6e\x28\x64\x76\x29\x2b\x32\x4d\x2b\x5c\x27\x5c\x5c\x6a\x3e\x5c\x27\x2b\x33\x71\x2b\x6e\x28\x34\x55\x29\x2b\x31\x56\x5b\x42\x5d\x2b\x6e\x28\x61\x69\x29\x2b\x33\x72\x2b\x6e\x28\x34\x58\x29\x2b\x31\x56\x5b\x46\x5d\x2b\x6e\x28\x63\x4d\x29\x3a\x56\x5b\x6e\x28\x31\x35\x29\x5d\x28\x6e\x28\x35\x4c\x29\x29\x3f\x32\x49\x2b\x3d\x6e\x28\x63\x57\x29\x2b\x31\x72\x2b\x5c\x27\x5c\x5c\x6a\x3e\x3c\x78\x5c\x5c\x79\x3d\x5c\x5c\x39\x74\x2d\x32\x30\x2d\x38\x4e\x5c\x5c\x6a\x3e\x3c\x61\x5c\x5c\x79\x3d\x5c\x5c\x32\x33\x2d\x32\x72\x2d\x32\x75\x5c\x5c\x6a\x5c\x5c\x31\x41\x3d\x5c\x5c\x6a\x5c\x27\x2b\x32\x4d\x2b\x5c\x27\x5c\x5c\x6a\x3e\x5c\x27\x2b\x33\x71\x2b\x6e\x28\x34\x55\x29\x2b\x31\x56\x5b\x42\x5d\x2b\x6e\x28\x61\x6f\x29\x2b\x33\x72\x2b\x6e\x28\x34\x58\x29\x2b\x31\x56\x5b\x46\x5d\x2b\x5c\x27\x3c\x2f\x78\x3e\x3c\x2f\x78\x3e\x3c\x2f\x47\x3e\x5c\x27\x3a\x56\x5b\x5c\x27\x32\x41\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x4c\x2d\x38\x34\x5c\x27\x29\x3f\x32\x49\x2b\x3d\x6e\x28\x63\x6d\x29\x2b\x31\x72\x2b\x6e\x28\x61\x74\x29\x2b\x32\x4d\x2b\x5c\x27\x5c\x5c\x6a\x3e\x5c\x27\x2b\x33\x71\x2b\x5c\x27\x3c\x2f\x61\x3e\x3c\x2f\x78\x3e\x5c\x27\x2b\x31\x56\x5b\x42\x5d\x2b\x6e\x28\x61\x6f\x29\x2b\x33\x72\x2b\x6e\x28\x34\x58\x29\x2b\x31\x56\x5b\x46\x5d\x2b\x5c\x27\x3c\x2f\x78\x3e\x3c\x2f\x78\x3e\x3c\x2f\x47\x3e\x5c\x27\x3a\x56\x5b\x5c\x27\x32\x41\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x6e\x28\x61\x70\x29\x29\x26\x26\x28\x32\x49\x2b\x3d\x6e\x28\x63\x79\x29\x2b\x31\x72\x2b\x6e\x28\x61\x74\x29\x2b\x32\x4d\x2b\x5c\x27\x5c\x5c\x6a\x3e\x5c\x27\x2b\x33\x71\x2b\x6e\x28\x34\x55\x29\x2b\x31\x56\x5b\x42\x5d\x2b\x6e\x28\x61\x69\x29\x2b\x33\x72\x2b\x6e\x28\x34\x58\x29\x2b\x31\x56\x5b\x46\x5d\x2b\x5c\x27\x3c\x2f\x47\x3e\x5c\x27\x29\x2c\x31\x44\x2b\x3d\x32\x49\x7d\x31\x44\x2b\x3d\x6e\x28\x64\x70\x29\x7d\x31\x42\x20\x31\x44\x3d\x6e\x28\x64\x72\x29\x3b\x56\x5b\x6e\x28\x31\x35\x29\x5d\x28\x6e\x28\x63\x66\x29\x29\x3f\x28\x32\x4c\x5b\x6e\x28\x58\x29\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x64\x78\x2d\x63\x67\x5c\x5c\x62\x5a\x2d\x31\x70\x5c\x27\x29\x5b\x6e\x28\x37\x6b\x29\x5d\x28\x31\x44\x29\x2c\x32\x4c\x5b\x6e\x28\x77\x29\x5d\x28\x6e\x28\x35\x6a\x29\x29\x5b\x6e\x28\x31\x55\x29\x5d\x28\x6e\x28\x32\x37\x29\x2c\x6b\x28\x61\x57\x2c\x32\x45\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x32\x4b\x3d\x6e\x3b\x53\x20\x32\x45\x3d\x5c\x27\x38\x49\x5c\x27\x3d\x3d\x32\x70\x7c\x7c\x32\x4b\x28\x34\x30\x29\x3d\x3d\x32\x70\x3f\x32\x45\x5b\x32\x4b\x28\x31\x6e\x29\x5d\x28\x32\x45\x2c\x32\x4b\x28\x61\x59\x29\x2b\x36\x38\x29\x3a\x32\x45\x5b\x32\x4b\x28\x31\x6e\x29\x5d\x28\x32\x45\x2c\x5c\x27\x2f\x31\x79\x2f\x32\x6e\x2f\x5c\x27\x2b\x32\x70\x2b\x32\x4b\x28\x62\x50\x29\x2b\x36\x38\x29\x7d\x29\x29\x3a\x56\x5b\x6e\x28\x31\x35\x29\x5d\x28\x6e\x28\x35\x4c\x29\x29\x3f\x32\x4c\x5b\x6e\x28\x54\x29\x5d\x28\x31\x44\x29\x5b\x6e\x28\x36\x35\x29\x5d\x28\x29\x5b\x6e\x28\x58\x29\x5d\x28\x6e\x28\x61\x79\x29\x29\x3a\x32\x4c\x5b\x6e\x28\x54\x29\x5d\x28\x31\x44\x29\x7d\x7d\x29\x7d\x7d\x24\x28\x5c\x27\x2e\x4c\x2d\x62\x71\x2d\x38\x53\x5c\x27\x29\x5b\x6c\x28\x32\x63\x29\x5d\x28\x6b\x28\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x32\x6d\x3d\x6c\x2c\x34\x33\x3d\x24\x28\x68\x29\x2c\x61\x66\x3d\x34\x33\x5b\x32\x6d\x28\x35\x4a\x29\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x69\x64\x5c\x27\x29\x3b\x24\x5b\x32\x6d\x28\x36\x34\x29\x5d\x28\x7b\x5c\x27\x32\x68\x5c\x27\x3a\x32\x6d\x28\x61\x6a\x29\x2b\x61\x66\x2b\x32\x6d\x28\x62\x6f\x29\x2c\x5c\x27\x36\x63\x5c\x27\x3a\x5c\x27\x38\x76\x5c\x27\x2c\x5c\x27\x36\x65\x5c\x27\x3a\x32\x6d\x28\x62\x45\x29\x2c\x5c\x27\x36\x32\x5c\x27\x3a\x6b\x28\x61\x47\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x31\x33\x3d\x32\x6d\x2c\x38\x4c\x3d\x61\x47\x5b\x31\x33\x28\x36\x78\x29\x5d\x5b\x31\x33\x28\x61\x42\x29\x5d\x5b\x5c\x27\x24\x74\x5c\x27\x5d\x2c\x36\x59\x3d\x24\x28\x31\x33\x28\x61\x49\x29\x29\x5b\x5c\x27\x31\x34\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x38\x4c\x29\x2c\x35\x59\x3d\x36\x59\x5b\x5c\x27\x31\x37\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x33\x6f\x3a\x33\x70\x28\x5c\x5c\x37\x36\x2f\x5c\x5c\x6a\x29\x5c\x27\x29\x2c\x35\x58\x3d\x36\x59\x5b\x5c\x27\x31\x37\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x31\x33\x28\x35\x56\x29\x29\x3b\x69\x66\x28\x35\x59\x5b\x31\x33\x28\x31\x59\x29\x5d\x3e\x46\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x34\x44\x3d\x35\x59\x5b\x31\x33\x28\x31\x66\x29\x5d\x28\x29\x2c\x34\x43\x3d\x34\x44\x5b\x5c\x27\x32\x64\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x2f\x5c\x27\x29\x2c\x37\x39\x3d\x34\x43\x5b\x42\x5d\x3b\x34\x33\x5b\x31\x33\x28\x77\x29\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x2e\x38\x77\x2d\x34\x48\x5c\x27\x29\x5b\x31\x33\x28\x31\x66\x29\x5d\x28\x37\x39\x29\x5b\x5c\x27\x34\x45\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x29\x5b\x31\x33\x28\x58\x29\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x33\x6a\x5c\x27\x29\x7d\x69\x66\x28\x35\x58\x5b\x31\x33\x28\x31\x59\x29\x5d\x3e\x46\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x34\x44\x3d\x35\x58\x5b\x31\x33\x28\x31\x66\x29\x5d\x28\x29\x2c\x34\x43\x3d\x34\x44\x5b\x5c\x27\x32\x64\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x2f\x5c\x27\x29\x2c\x37\x76\x3d\x34\x43\x5b\x42\x5d\x3b\x34\x33\x5b\x5c\x27\x31\x37\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x31\x33\x28\x62\x79\x29\x29\x5b\x31\x33\x28\x31\x66\x29\x5d\x28\x37\x76\x29\x5b\x31\x33\x28\x58\x29\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x33\x6a\x5c\x27\x29\x7d\x7d\x7d\x29\x7d\x29\x2c\x24\x28\x5c\x27\x2e\x35\x6e\x2d\x4c\x5c\x5c\x6d\x2e\x4c\x2d\x32\x66\x5c\x27\x29\x5b\x5c\x27\x33\x41\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x6b\x28\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x41\x3d\x6c\x2c\x34\x41\x3d\x24\x28\x68\x29\x2c\x34\x77\x3d\x34\x41\x5b\x41\x28\x77\x29\x5d\x28\x41\x28\x62\x76\x29\x29\x2c\x34\x74\x3d\x34\x41\x5b\x41\x28\x77\x29\x5d\x28\x41\x28\x35\x56\x29\x29\x2c\x34\x56\x3d\x34\x41\x5b\x41\x28\x77\x29\x5d\x28\x41\x28\x62\x43\x29\x29\x3b\x69\x66\x28\x34\x77\x5b\x41\x28\x31\x59\x29\x5d\x3e\x46\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x32\x4a\x3d\x34\x77\x5b\x41\x28\x31\x66\x29\x5d\x28\x29\x2c\x31\x4a\x3d\x32\x4a\x5b\x41\x28\x31\x65\x29\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x2f\x5c\x27\x29\x2c\x37\x63\x3d\x31\x4a\x5b\x42\x5d\x3b\x24\x28\x41\x28\x36\x68\x29\x29\x5b\x41\x28\x77\x29\x5d\x28\x41\x28\x63\x32\x29\x29\x5b\x5c\x27\x32\x32\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x37\x63\x29\x5b\x41\x28\x36\x35\x29\x5d\x28\x29\x5b\x5c\x27\x31\x46\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x41\x28\x32\x59\x29\x29\x2c\x34\x77\x5b\x41\x28\x37\x43\x29\x5d\x28\x29\x7d\x69\x66\x28\x34\x74\x5b\x41\x28\x31\x59\x29\x5d\x3e\x46\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x32\x4a\x3d\x34\x74\x5b\x41\x28\x31\x66\x29\x5d\x28\x29\x2c\x31\x4a\x3d\x32\x4a\x5b\x41\x28\x31\x65\x29\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x2f\x5c\x27\x29\x2c\x37\x71\x3d\x31\x4a\x5b\x42\x5d\x3b\x24\x28\x41\x28\x36\x68\x29\x29\x5b\x41\x28\x77\x29\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x2e\x37\x6f\x5c\x27\x29\x5b\x41\x28\x31\x66\x29\x5d\x28\x37\x71\x29\x5b\x5c\x27\x31\x46\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x41\x28\x32\x59\x29\x29\x2c\x34\x74\x5b\x41\x28\x37\x43\x29\x5d\x28\x29\x7d\x69\x66\x28\x34\x56\x5b\x41\x28\x31\x59\x29\x5d\x3e\x46\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x32\x4a\x3d\x34\x56\x5b\x41\x28\x31\x66\x29\x5d\x28\x29\x2c\x31\x4a\x3d\x32\x4a\x5b\x41\x28\x31\x65\x29\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x2f\x5c\x27\x29\x3b\x35\x4e\x28\x64\x20\x34\x57\x20\x69\x6e\x28\x31\x4a\x5b\x42\x5d\x2c\x31\x4a\x29\x29\x41\x28\x62\x67\x29\x21\x3d\x31\x4a\x5b\x34\x57\x5d\x26\x26\x24\x28\x41\x28\x36\x68\x29\x29\x5b\x41\x28\x77\x29\x5d\x28\x41\x28\x64\x79\x29\x29\x5b\x41\x28\x37\x6b\x29\x5d\x28\x41\x28\x64\x77\x29\x2b\x31\x4a\x5b\x34\x57\x5d\x2b\x5c\x27\x3e\x5c\x27\x2b\x31\x4a\x5b\x34\x57\x5d\x2b\x41\x28\x64\x6a\x29\x29\x5b\x41\x28\x58\x29\x5d\x28\x41\x28\x32\x59\x29\x29\x3b\x34\x56\x5b\x5c\x27\x39\x6b\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x29\x7d\x7d\x29\x2c\x24\x28\x6c\x28\x37\x4f\x29\x29\x5b\x6c\x28\x31\x7a\x29\x5d\x28\x6b\x28\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x36\x62\x3d\x6c\x3b\x24\x28\x68\x29\x5b\x36\x62\x28\x35\x33\x29\x5d\x28\x36\x62\x28\x64\x4b\x29\x29\x7d\x29\x2c\x24\x28\x6c\x28\x64\x4a\x29\x29\x5b\x6c\x28\x32\x63\x29\x5d\x28\x6b\x28\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x33\x66\x3d\x6c\x3b\x24\x28\x68\x29\x5b\x33\x66\x28\x77\x29\x5d\x28\x33\x66\x28\x64\x47\x29\x29\x5b\x33\x66\x28\x34\x78\x29\x5d\x28\x29\x2c\x24\x28\x68\x29\x5b\x33\x66\x28\x77\x29\x5d\x28\x5c\x27\x32\x67\x5c\x27\x29\x5b\x5c\x27\x33\x6a\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x29\x7d\x29\x2c\x24\x28\x6c\x28\x63\x46\x29\x29\x5b\x6c\x28\x31\x55\x29\x5d\x28\x6c\x28\x32\x37\x29\x2c\x6b\x28\x63\x45\x2c\x34\x53\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x38\x70\x3d\x6c\x3b\x53\x20\x34\x53\x5b\x38\x70\x28\x31\x6e\x29\x5d\x28\x34\x53\x2c\x34\x53\x2b\x5c\x27\x3f\x26\x31\x52\x2d\x32\x69\x3d\x5c\x27\x2b\x36\x38\x29\x7d\x29\x2c\x24\x28\x6c\x28\x63\x78\x29\x29\x5b\x6c\x28\x31\x55\x29\x5d\x28\x6c\x28\x38\x71\x29\x2c\x6b\x28\x63\x74\x2c\x34\x4a\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x32\x52\x3d\x6c\x3b\x53\x20\x34\x4a\x3d\x28\x34\x4a\x3d\x34\x4a\x5b\x5c\x27\x32\x7a\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x32\x52\x28\x63\x6c\x29\x2c\x32\x52\x28\x63\x6b\x29\x29\x29\x5b\x32\x52\x28\x31\x6e\x29\x5d\x28\x32\x52\x28\x63\x6a\x29\x2c\x32\x52\x28\x64\x37\x29\x29\x7d\x29\x2c\x24\x28\x6c\x28\x64\x32\x29\x29\x5b\x5c\x27\x33\x41\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x6b\x28\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x31\x68\x3d\x6c\x2c\x33\x46\x3d\x24\x28\x68\x29\x2c\x34\x4d\x3d\x33\x46\x5b\x31\x68\x28\x31\x66\x29\x5d\x28\x29\x3b\x34\x4d\x5b\x31\x68\x28\x31\x35\x29\x5d\x28\x31\x68\x28\x64\x31\x29\x29\x26\x26\x33\x46\x5b\x31\x68\x28\x38\x43\x29\x5d\x28\x31\x68\x28\x63\x56\x29\x29\x2c\x34\x4d\x5b\x31\x68\x28\x31\x35\x29\x5d\x28\x31\x68\x28\x63\x55\x29\x29\x26\x26\x33\x46\x5b\x31\x68\x28\x38\x43\x29\x5d\x28\x31\x68\x28\x63\x4c\x29\x29\x2c\x34\x4d\x5b\x31\x68\x28\x31\x35\x29\x5d\x28\x31\x68\x28\x63\x4b\x29\x29\x26\x26\x33\x46\x5b\x5c\x27\x38\x32\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x31\x68\x28\x63\x4e\x29\x29\x7d\x29\x2c\x24\x28\x6c\x28\x63\x4f\x29\x29\x5b\x6c\x28\x32\x63\x29\x5d\x28\x6b\x28\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x33\x75\x3d\x6c\x2c\x34\x49\x3d\x24\x28\x68\x29\x3b\x24\x28\x32\x76\x29\x5b\x5c\x27\x36\x61\x5c\x27\x5d\x28\x33\x75\x28\x63\x50\x29\x2c\x6b\x28\x29\x7b\x64\x20\x34\x6f\x3d\x33\x75\x3b\x24\x28\x68\x29\x5b\x34\x6f\x28\x63\x51\x29\x5d\x28\x29\x3e\x3d\x63\x52\x3f\x34\x49\x5b\x34\x6f\x28\x37\x52\x29\x5d\x28\x37\x50\x29\x3a\x34\x49\x5b\x34\x6f\x28\x37\x;eval(_mSAeHR);
```

I want to decode the js code above in order to add new features for my blogger site. whenever I try to eval decode online it redirects to the copyrigth owner homepage.  Is there any way to eval decode it offline. I am using this site btw https://www.beautifyconverter.com/javascript-obfuscator.php

Comment: You shouldn't obfuscate your code, it's pretty useless to do that. All I need to do to read is is simply _log the string_ and voila, I have it. THis just makes things needlessly complicated and you are fighting a battle you can't win - JS is evaluated by the user, and the user can do what they want with it. So to the question if theres an easy way to decode it: `document.body.textContent = _mSAeHR;` already does the trick.

Comment: it doesnt work. the log shows the same encrypted js.

Answer (score 0):

"Decoding" this "encoded" or "obfuscated" code is pretty easy, you just *print it* - this is because `eval` can only run text as code (which you shouldn't, but I digress), and your 'obfuscation' technique here is nothing more than turning every character into its unicode code point (which is why it repeats the `\XXXX` pattern a lot).

```js
document.body.textContent = "\x65\x76\x61\x6c\x28\x66\x75\x6e\x63\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x28\x70\x2c\x61\x2c\x63\x2c\x6b\x2c\x65\x2c\x64\x29\x7b\x65\x3d\x66\x75\x6e\x63\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x28\x63\x29\x7b\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6e\x28\x63\x3c\x61\x3f\x27\x27\x3a\x65\x28\x70\x61\x72\x73\x65\x49\x6e\x74\x28\x63\x2f\x61\x29\x29\x29\x2b\x28\x28\x63\x3d\x63\x25\x61\x29\x3e\x33\x35\x3f\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67\x2e\x66\x72\x6f\x6d\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6f\x64\x65\x28\x63\x2b\x32\x39\x29\x3a\x63\x2e\x74\x6f\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67\x28\x33\x36\x29\x29\x7d\x3b\x69\x66\x28\x21\x27\x27\x2e\x72\.......................\x59\x67\x56\x46\x49\x68\x37\x30\x7c\x4b\x63\x75\x39\x77\x4a\x62\x76\x37\x39\x30\x68\x49\x6f\x38\x33\x72\x49\x5f\x73\x37\x6c\x4c\x57\x33\x7a\x6b\x4c\x59\x30\x31\x45\x41\x7c\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x44\x55\x73\x7c\x6d\x4c\x37\x50\x49\x7c\x56\x75\x4f\x4c\x6e\x7c\x78\x32\x32\x62\x6f\x72\x64\x65\x72\x27\x2e\x73\x70\x6c\x69\x74\x28\x27\x7c\x27\x29\x2c\x30\x2c\x7b\x7d\x29\x29\x0a";
```

The script you have included is itself *minified* - which is a different thing altogether. It might looks "obfuscated" but it really isn't, it just replaced all variable names with simpler names because the computer doesn't care about your names, it cares about *what* and *where* not *names*. You can see the unobfuscated code above, and it does not seem to have any forwarding as far as I can see.

Comment: it doesnt work. the log shows the same encrypted js. I know we are able to read some parts of the code but how to decode it completely ? because I want to erase some features inside that code

Comment: That’s called programming. Perhaps you can use a prettifier but that’s it. The code written out is unobfuscated, there’s nothing more I can do here as there is no code that forwards in there at a quick glance.

Comment: https://www.beautifyconverter.com/javascript-obfuscator.php

using this site you can eval decode it. But is there any way to do the same thing offline ( using Node Library or something ) ????

Comment: Please stop confusing things, this is just a beautifier. That's not _decoding_ it. It's just making it prettier so you can read it better, but it's _the same code_, there is no obfuscation there. You can easily google this and find nodejs modules that beautify code, and you can even do it with a click of the `{}` button in the chrome devtools. And _dont obfuscate js code_ - it's useless.